# What is the shell command to grep multiple strings?

Tags: shell

What is the shell command to grep multiple strings? 
For an input text[output of a command] i need to check whether few strings are there or not. Will return true if all strings are present, else false(AND operation).

Example1: Input: What is the shell command to grep multiple strings? For an input text[output of a command] i need to check whether few strings are there or not. Will return true if all strings are present, else false(AND operation).

Search for strings "need" "check" "few" "AND"

Output: True

Exapmle 2: What is the shell command to grep multiple strings? For an input text[output of a command] i need to check whether few strings are there or not. Will return true if all strings are present, else false

Search for strings "need" "check" "few" "AND"

Output: False

Comment: Can you explain by giving some example what you need?

Comment: I want to cat a log file and want to check if all my needed strings are there.

Example I want to check if ("time", "word", "apple" "fine") all the strings are present in log.

Comment: Do you mean all the words in your file? Do you mean all the words in a line?

Comment: I mean all the three strings shall be there in my log. Sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: Example1:
Input: What is the shell command to grep multiple strings? For an input text[output of a command] i need to check whether few strings are there or not. Will return true if all strings are present, else false(AND operation).

Search for strings "need" "check" "few" "AND"

Output: True

Exapmle 2:
What is the shell command to grep multiple strings? For an input text[output of a command] i need to check whether few strings are there or not. Will return true if all strings are present, else false
Search for strings "need" "check" "few" "AND"

Output: False

Comment: Thanks updated the answer now. Make your clarifications in your questions itself and not as the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean, "are all search targets present *someplace* in the file", then you can do

```
   awk '/need/{n=1}/check/{c=1}/few/{f=1}/AND/{A=1}
       END{exit (!(n&&c&&f&&A))}' file2search
```

echo $? will return 0 when all are found in the file, and 1 when any or all are missing infile.

If you mean "are all search targets on the same line", then you can do

```
  awk '{ if ($0 ~ /need/ && $0 ~ /check/ && $0 ~ /few/ && $0 ~ /AND/) lineMatched=1 }
      END { if (lineMatched) exit 0 ; else exit 1 }' file2Search
```

echo $? will work the same way for this.

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
$cat test.txt
name1 is a boy
name2 is a girl
name3 is a good person
name4 is unknown to me
$ grep -q "name1" test.txt && grep -q "name2" test.txt
$ echo $?
0
$ grep -q "name1" test.txt && grep -q "helloWorld" test.txt
$ echo $?
1
```

With grep you are searching for each pattern. If any of them fails to find the pattern in the file, it will exit with 1 status. So in my second example, first grep succeeds and return 0 while second returns 1 and hence when you enquire exit status it says 1. With this, you could check whether you found all the patterns in a file or not.